# QLineEdit -- how to enter single value -- with no spaces

Tags: qt, qlineedit, qtgui

I have made an editor in which i have to enter a Hex or decimal value in each field. Here the field i am using is QLineEdit.

Now requirement is that each Qlineedit box accept only one value without spaces. Then i can read this text value & convert it directly from string to decimal.

Is it possible to make QlineEdit to accept only one value without spaces ? Boxes in below figure are QLineEdit.

I do not want to use combo box here.

[image]

Comment: Can't you just remove the spaces before converting or how does an example of a problematic input look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on Lego Stormtroopr's answer, I think QValidator is a good and simple option. For example

```
dialog->lineedit1->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator( QRegExp("[0-9]{1,20}"), this ));
```

Here, the QRegExp denotes that you shall only accept digits from 0 to 9 and no other key-presses (spaces or letters) and you shall accept atleast 1 and maximum 20 characters (digits). You then set your lineedit's validator to this value. For more information, you can visit http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qregexp.html

or for a double,

```
QDoubleValidator *myDblVal = new QDoubleValidator( 0.0, MAX_VALUE, 1, this);
myDblVal->setNotation( QDoubleValidator::StandardNotation );
dialog->lineedit1->setValidator( myDblVal );
```

Here you simply use the inbuilt Qt functionality for double validation. You shall only accept a decimal between 0 and MAX_VALUE.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here ..?

Comment: thanks ... i will try this... can you also write one statement for ... accepting Hex value ...

Comment: What format of hex value do you plan to enter. If it is a simple hex number then [0-9A-Fa-f] would suffice. For any other format following link may give you some idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760206/qvalidator-for-hex-input

Answer (score 2):

If the answer was just decimal, I'd suggest you use a [QSpinBox](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qspinbox.html) instead. I did find a thread on how to implement a [Hexidecimal SpinBox](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/20399-QT-Creator-Spin-Box-for-hex-values), but unfortunately the link to the third-party widget is dead. However it does say you could:

> subclass QSpinBox and reimplement textFromValue() and valueFromText() to show hexadecimal values.

With the right Decimal-to-Hexidecimal function (you don't mention what language you are using) this would be a suitable solution.

The other alternative, is to use the [QLineEdit.setValidator](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setValidator) function with a custom subclass of [QValidator](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvalidator.html) to provide a validation method. For this, just re-implement the [QValidator.validate](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvalidator.html#validate) function to check what a "valid" value.

Comment: I am using c++ language.

Comment: BTW that link to qxt was old here is the current link:http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxtbasespinbox.html